# Dynamic svg in Next.js 13

Tags: next.js, svg-react-loader

In brief: This component is working in Next.js v12, but doesn't work in Next.js v13

```
import React, { FC } from 'react'
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

// const DynamicComponent = (name:string) => dynamic(() => import(`/public/assets/svg/github.svg`))
const DynamicComponent = (name: string) => dynamic(() => import(`/public/assets/svg/${name}.svg`));

const Asvg:FC<any> = ({ name, ...props}) => {
   let Icon = DynamicComponent(name)
   return (
     <Icon {...props}/>
   )
 }

export default Asvg
```

I have found that it render, if, instead of the name variable, I will put just string.

Here's the error. It seems that it was able to find the src somehow, but it won't render the svg.
[image]

Also, it seems, that just importing the component produces the error. I don't need even to initialize component to see this error.